# Greater Rift Keystone drop rate and requirements?

Tags: diablo-iii

The Greater Rift Keystone drop rate is 100% for T6 and maybe 75% for T1, lower for lower difficulties and chance of 2 dropping in higher difficulties. Is there any empirical data that confirms rates?

Edit: drop rates were changed in a hotfix on Sept 3, 2014:

> The drop rate for Key of Trials has been significantly increased (9/3)

Edit: difficulty requirement was removed in patch 2.3 on Aug 25, 2015:

> Generic Greater Rift Keystones now drop and can drop at any difficulty level

Confirmed level 70 required.

I'd still like to know approximate drop rates on all difficulties if anyone has data/insight.

Comment: There are no posts on this as of yet. T1 and 70 are required. You can see the psuedo rates I posted here: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/182521/25404 and I will update them when there is more actual information released or available.

Comment: Aren't these drop rates the same as keys for infernal machine?

Comment: @BenLefebvre - They are not, because for example the keys drop at a 50% rate on T6 and the keystone drops at a 100% rate on T6.

Comment: I'd recommend removing the request for blue/green posts.  Those requests are off-topic.  We can test and give empirical evidence, so it's objective, but specifically asking us to hunt down what developers have said isn't something we do.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are Greater Nephalem Rifts and how do they work?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/182501/what-are-greater-nephalem-rifts-and-how-do-they-work)

Answer (score 1):

This may be just an approximate answer. But as far as I tested it, I've checked it on my game.

You reference that T6 will provide a 100% drop chance. As far as I tested it, this won't be true. I have played some T6 portals and I gt some keys, which is great, but also some runs without any key.

There is a [reference](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/11759886255#3) on the net which says it **could** be 100%. But in my experience they are much lower. As everytime were a percentage chance exists, it won't be possible to pin it down to an exact value without viewing the code. But regarding my drop chance experiences the drop chance base seems to be like the [drop rate for the infernal machine](http://www.diablowiki.net/Infernal_Machine) which is described below.

- Torment I: 25%
- Torment II: 28%
- Torment III: 33%
- Torment IV: 38%
- Torment V: 43%
- Torment VI: 50%